# https.createServer error: SSL_CTX_use_certificate: ca md too weak

Tags: node.js, express, ssl, https, openssl

I am trying to implement peer certificate validation in node.js with express.
In the production i receive error: EE certificate key too weak.

How can i change it to support the weak key?
I don't want to ignore it in the code level, because if i am doing that it does not check the CA at all.
In the development server, if i remove the matching CA certificate i receive UNABLE_TO_VERIFY_LEAF_SIGNATURE, while in the production server i receive "EE certificate key too weak" - it does not check it at all.

In the development server it is working correctly, but in the production server i receive the error.

I cannot change the certificate on the client devices, so i must support the weak key.

```
https.createServer({
    key: getFile(config.get("ssl_certificate.key")),
    cert: getFile(config.get("ssl_certificate.cert")),
    ca: [
        getCACertFile('ca-crt.pem'), //some certificates
    ],
    requestCert: true,
    rejectUnauthorized: false
},app)
```

In req.socket.authorizationError, i expect to receive null.
In the development server i receive null, but in the production server i receive "EE certificate key too weak"

stderrs:

```
error: failed to start server: Error: error:140AB18E:SSL routines:SSL_CTX_use_certificate:ca md too weak
    at Object.createSecureContext (_tls_common.js:135:17)
    at Server (_tls_wrap.js:873:27)
    at new Server (https.js:62:14)
    at Object.createServer (https.js:85:10)
```

Comment: hi, I have tried to fix this question but failed. 
Would you share your final solution with me ?

Answer (score 1):

[Node v10.0.0 Release News](https://nodejs.org/en/blog/release/v10.0.0/)

```
Dependencies
V8 has been updated to 6.6. [9daebb48d6]
OpenSSL has been updated to 1.1.0h. [66cb29e646]
```

If you are using Node.js>=10.0.0, it will raise the exception if certs are encrypted by sha1 or md5.

- Generate new certs `encrypted by sha256` will fix the question on Server.
- But in your case, since the certs has been used for devices to connect to server, you can simply `use Node.js<10.0.0` (eg:v8.x) to start the server.

Besides, suggest to use nvm to control versions of Node.js.

```
nvm use v8.x.x
node server.js
```

Answer (score 0):

Two aspects of your typical SSL cert immediately jump to one's mind: RSA key length, and the hash algorithm. The recipe to accept the cert might differ based on which one is weak.

Check the cert properties, under `Siganture Algorithm`. Is it `sha1RSA` by any chance? If so, search for enabling SHA1 support.

Check the public key. How many bits in it? Is it less than 1024? Then search for minimum RSA key length setting.